# Visual Studio 2015 not running WPF or UWP apps

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, runtime-error, visual-studio-2015

For some reason every time I run a UWP app on local machine it just shows me the app splash screen and doesn't continue. This happens even with brand new apps with no additions to the code.

I also tried making a WPF program to see if that would work and it didn't either. In that case it gave me a dialog box stating:

> Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting for an operation to 
>   complete. If you regularly encounter this delay during normal 
>   usage please report this problem to Microsoft. Please include 
>   a description of the work you were doing in Microsoft Visual 
>   Studio and when possible instructions on how to reproduce 
>   this delay.
>
> If Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting on another application 
>   you can switch to that application now, or you can continue 
>   waiting for this operation to complete.

Here is a screenshot of what I get with a UWP app:

[image]

Comment: That is really odd. Maybe try running repair on Visual Studio?

Comment: Thanks @Matt, that seemed to resolve the issue. Do you want to post it as an answer so that I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running repair on Visual Studio. Sometimes it can get wonky!